# I am relatively new to Python, I was wondering how to see if two words in a string are the same like this:

Tags: python-3.x, split, string-comparison

How do you compare to see if two words side by side in a string are the same. For instance if the string "Hello world, how how are you doing today" was imported how would I write code to say that the word "how" is repeated in that sentence. I know I would start with something like this but have no clue where to go after.

x=input("Please type a sentence.")

x.split()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a great language to start, I suggest using a dictionary. You can split the string into words and then, count and store the occurrence of each word into a dictionary, then call the dictionary to see how many times a word is repeated.

```
mystring = "Hello world, how how are you doing today"
words = mystring.split()
mydict = {}
for word in words:
    if word in mydict:
        mydict[word] += 1
    else:
        mydict[word] = 1

print(mydict['how'])
```

**Update**

```
mystring = "Hello world, how how are you doing today"
words = mystring.split()

lastword = ""
for word in words:
    if lastword.lower() == word.lower():
        print("The word " + word + " is repeated")
        break
    lastword = word
```

Comment: Well I only want to know if word is immediately repeated by the same word. If the Example was "Hello World, how how are you today world?" I wouldn't care about the word "world" but only about "how"

Comment: Then I think I would just loop through each word and store the current word and compare it against the next one (case insensitive), if it matches then I know I've got two consecutive words.